# Ошибка TypeError: startswith() takes at most 3 arguments (11 given) в боте на discord.py (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

сегодня решил добавить сообщение о неправильно написанной команде -help.
Но мне мешает одна ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\bot\bot.py", line 250, in on_message
    if message.content.startswith('-рудз', '-hlrp', '-hrlp', '-herlp', '-helo', '-helrp', '-рдкз', '-ркдз', '-рукдз', '-рудщ', '-рудкз'):
TypeError: startswith() takes at most 3 arguments (11 given)
```

---

Код:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('-рудз', '-hlrp', '-hrlp', '-herlp', '-helo', '-helrp', '-рдкз', '-ркдз', '-рукдз', '-рудщ', '-рудкз'):
        def on_message(ctx):
            author = ctx.message.author
            embed=discord.Embed(description=f'{author.mention}, Неизвестная команда. Возможно вы имели ввиду `-help`.', color=0x2f3136)
            ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after = 3)
            sleep(1)
            ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) принимает различные варианты префиксов в первом параметре как кортеж.

Попробуйте так:

```
if message.content.startswith(('-рудз', '-hlrp', '-hrlp', '-herlp', '-helo', '-helrp', '-рдкз', '-ркдз', '-рукдз', '-рудщ', '-рудкз')):
```

---

Из документации:

```
str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])
```

> Return True if string starts with the prefix, otherwise return False.
> **prefix can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for**. With optional
> start, test string beginning at that position. With optional end, stop
> comparing string at that position.